# Substring in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, substring

I was wondering if there was a substring function in excel VBA that would allow me to extract a string based on start and end positions? I know there is left and right but they only allow a length and my substring could be variable length. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Mid Function
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: That just allows start and length...Is there that allows start and end?

Comment: @Philip why don't you tell us about the actual problem you face instead of asking for a specific function that you think you need. I smell an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`Mid()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function as @Jason_Walker suggested.

Since you seem to know where your end point is, you can calculate the length (as required by `Mid()`) as `End - Start + 1`.